# Usar tamanho da tela em 100%

Tags: html, css

Tenho duas divs,

DIV 1 com 80% de largura, centralizada e tenho a DIV 2 que está dentro da DIV 1, que quero que esteja com 100% de largura, mas, como ela está dentro da DIV 1 que tem 80%, então, 100% passa a ser os 100% da DIV 1 (Virando 80%). Mas quero que a DIV 2 tenha 100% da largura ta tela, mesmo estando dentro da DIV 1, tem como fazer isso?

```
<div class="1"> <!--TEM 80%-->
<div class="2"></div><!--TEM 100%, ou seja, pega o total da DIV1, mas quero que seja 100% da TELA TODA---->
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tente usar `width:100vw;` que vai pegar o tamanho total da tela, caso queira reduzir algum valor basta usar `width:calc(100vw - 20px);`

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, era pra ate dar certo, mas não da, conforme minha print, ele ignora parece o position absolut e começa a contar a tela a partir da div e não da tela.

Comment: Lembrando que eu não usei **%** e sim **vw**. Segundo, você tem algum `position:relative` antes desta div?

Comment: Ja achei, Guilherme, mas tinha sim, outro na div pai, ai com a ajuda do Mathias consegui resolver, mas obrigado também!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar a propriedade [`position: absolute;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) na `<div class="2">`, segue um snippet de exemplo:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 20px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Então, eu estava fazendo isso, tentando, mas mesmo com o position absolut no meu site não funciona, ele fica 100% do tamanho da div 1 e não da tela toda, não sei o por que.

Comment: Estranho, tenta colocar um snippet que reproduza esse problema aqui na pergunta, ai talvez eu edite minha resposta p/ te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Olha a print Mathias, não consigo reproduzir em snippet 100% porque é meio grande, ve se com a print consegue entender.

Comment: Entendi sim, @LucasCarvalho tenta dar uma olhada se algum elemento pai está com `position:relative;` isso pode impedir o elemento de ficar com `width:100%;`.

Comment: O Pai também está com position absolut, ai removi pra testar e a té funcionou, mas ai desconfigura o pai. Vou ter que pensar num jeito...